# R 3.4.1: configure fails on SLES 11.4 with libpcre error

Tags: r, pcre

I'm currently trying to install R 3.4.1 on a SLES 11.4 system. The system libraries, namely libbz2, liblzma, and libpcre are far too old so I installed my own versions. This worked fine for libbz2 and liblzma, but after installing libpcre, configure still fails with

```
checking for pcre_fullinfo in -lpcre... yes
checking pcre.h usability... yes
checking pcre.h presence... yes
checking for pcre.h... yes
checking pcre/pcre.h usability... no
checking pcre/pcre.h presence... no
checking for pcre/pcre.h... no
checking if PCRE version >= 8.20, < 10.0 and has UTF-8 support... no
checking whether PCRE support suffices... configure: error: pcre >= 8.20 library and headers are required
```

pcre 8.41 was configured with

```
./configure --prefix=/hpc/rhome/software/R/3.4.1 --enable-unicode-properties --enable-pcre16 --enable-pcre32 --enable-pcregrep-libz --enable-pcregrep-libbz2 --enable-pcretest-libreadline --enable-static
```

I only tried with just the unicode options with the same result.

`pcretest -C` gives me

```
PCRE version 8.41 2017-07-05
Compiled with
  8-bit support
  UTF-8 support
  16-bit support
  UTF-16 support
  32-bit support
  UTF-32 support
  Unicode properties support
  No just-in-time compiler support
  Newline sequence is LF
  \R matches all Unicode newlines
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Parentheses nest limit = 250
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack
```

Full output of R's configure is at https://gist.github.com/391a5f83373b555ef523e0739f78784d.

Full config.log is at https://gist.github.com/7ea9f5996866aa6f756979926038d83a.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Manuel

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with the help of a colleague: I need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH as well, otherwise configure will find the library for compiling but any test binaries generated won't find it.